# show data in group by formate

Tags: sql, join, group-by

```
Name       Status
A           Fail
B           open 
c           fail
A           Success
A           open
A           Success
```

I want Output like,

```
Name   S_open   S_Success   S_All
A        1        2          4
B        1        0          1
C        0        0          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT Name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Status='open' THEN 1 END) AS S_open,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Status='Success' THEN 1 END) AS S_Success,
   SUM(1) AS S_All
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this;

```
SELECT 
       upper(name),
       SUM(S_OPEN) S_open,
       SUM(S_SUCCESS) S_Success,
       count(*) S_All
FROM 
(
       select name, 
              CASE WHEN upper(status) = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END S_OPEN,
              CASE WHEN upper(status) = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END S_SUCCESS
       from TABLE
) t
GROUP BY upper(name) order by 1
```